# Duplicate columns values to fit column names array

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to duplicate `u` to fit `d_range`. In clear i would like to put d_range in column names and repeat values as needed to fit the array. In this case the `d_range` is 
     `DatetimeIndex(['2019-06-24', '2019-06-25'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')`

current output:

```
      balance
BTC     5000
ETH    10000
BCH     1046
```

my code:

```
d_range = pd.date_range(start= datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1), datetime.min.time()),   end= datetime.combine(datetime.today() , datetime.min.time()) )
currency = np.array(['BTC','ETH','BCH'])
u = np.array([5000,10000,1046])
cl_bal = pd.DataFrame(u, index= currency, dtype= int)
cl_bal.columns = ['balance'] * len(cl_bal.columns)
```

Comment: What is expected output? MultiIndex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with `np.repeat`:

```
cl_bal = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(u, len(d_range)), 
                     index= pd.MultiIndex.from_product([currency, d_range]), 
                     dtype= int)
print (cl_bal)
                    0
BTC 2019-06-24   5000
    2019-06-25   5000
ETH 2019-06-24  10000
    2019-06-25  10000
BCH 2019-06-24   1046
    2019-06-25   1046
```